# Filling user card with the information from the form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create the card which is filled with the information as soon as the user types something into the form. For example, he enters his name and the name appears on the card. The page shouldn't be reloaded, the info on the card must appear instantly.

Comment: you have not asked a question. you should show what you have tried (a sample program) and explain how it isn't working. then we can help explain how to correct it

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but the problem is I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Just show what you have tried. It does not matter if it is wrong, that is what this SO is for. We are not here to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the `onkeyup` event listener to immediately translate whatever value exists inside the form field to wherever the output is on the card.

(To be honest, I'm not absolutely sure what you mean by *"the card"*).

**Working Example:**

```js
const firstName = document.getElementsByClassName('firstname')[0];
const firstNameOutput = document.getElementsByClassName('first-name-output')[0];

const showFirstName = () => firstNameOutput.textContent = firstName.value;

firstname.addEventListener('keyup', showFirstName, false);
```

```css
form,
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 8%;
}

.card {
  height: 36px;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.card h2,
.card p {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.card h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Details</legend>
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" class="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name..." />
</fieldset>
</form>

<section class="card">
<h2>First Name:</h2>
<p class="first-name-output"></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for help! Basically, the idea was just to put the content of input into another element (on 'the card' so to say) as soon as user types anything.

The function turned out to be very simple

```
     email.oninput = function() {
      emailResult.innerHTML = email.value;
    };
```

For those who may face the same problem, I used this resource: https://javascript.info/events-change-input

Comment: As you get better at javascript you will see the code you have added above is essentially the same as the code in the answer I posted. That is to say: `email.oninput = function () {...}` serves the same purpose as `firstname.addEventListener('keyup', showFirstName, false);` and `emailResult.innerHTML` serves the same purpose as `firstNameOutput.textContent`. In fact, you ***should*** be using the property `textContent` rather than the property `innerHTML`.

Comment: @ DeeRi, if you want to say "Thanks a lot for help!" on Stack Overflow then please upvote the answer by the contributor you are saying thank you to. (ie. press the upwards arrow above the number on the left hand side of the answer.)